# Bootstrap Glyphicons - Positioning Problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am trying to move the position of a glyphicon in Bootstrap 3 from underneath a username, to next to it, but I cannot get it to move. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="well sidebarbox">

<div class="avatar large pull-left">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/<?php echo $this->GetCurrentUserData('name')?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->GetStorageUrl('avatar') . $this->GetCurrentUserData('avatar')?>">
    </a>
</div>

<strong><?php echo $this->GetCurrentUserData('screen_name')?></strong>
<?php $current_user_meta = Zend_Registry::get('current_user_meta');?>
<?php if (isset($current_user_meta['badges'])):?>
    <div class="network-badges horizontal">
        <?php echo $this->partial('/partial/badges.phtml', array('badges' => $current_user_meta['badges']));?>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<hr />

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/editprofile/edit"><?php echo $this->translate('Edit Profile');?></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/search/posts"><?php echo $this->translate('All Posts');?></a>
    </li>       
</ul>

</div>
```

And here is my CSS Code:

```
.network-badges.vertical{
padding-left: 1px;
}

.network-badges.horizontal{
white-space: nowrap;
}

.network-badges.vertical{
max-width: 64px;
}

.network-badges .network-badge{
margin: 3px 3px 0 3px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Currently, the output is this:

```
Richard Evans
[glyphicon]
```

And I want it to be

```
Richard Evans [glyphicon]
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of the resulting page? At first glance I'd say you should put the username in a div and float all the divs to the left.

Comment: Yeah, if you look check this out, you'll see what the outputted: www.startrekrisa.com/Picture1.png

Comment: Oh cheers! I've managed to it! :D Thanks

Comment: This is a _"Please fix my code"_ type of question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell what you're doing here and I can't see what version of bootstrap you are using, let's assume 3.

The documentation is here http://getbootstrap.com/components/

generally if you want to use a glyph you do things like this

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Username
```

I have found that the space between the glyph and the text is important to maintain

for a hyperlink it might look like this

```
<a href"...">Username <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a>
```

It is really that simple.

The best advice I can give you is to perhaps make your UI in HTML before introducing the dynamic text jsFiddle is a good place to practice.

Answer (score 1):

`glyphicon` class in `bootstrap.css` are left positioned for default because all `'glyphicon-*'` classes have a psedo class associated which put icon before component. 
For example:

```
.glyphicon-asterisk:before {
  content: "\2a";
}
.glyphicon-plus:before {
  content: "\2b";
}
.glyphicon-euro:before {
  content: "\20ac";
}
```

and so on.

If you really want put icon to the right, you must 'override' class, cleaning the `before` pseudo and create a new one for `after`, like this:

```
.glyphicon-asterisk:before {
    content: "";
}

.glyphicon-asterisk:after {
    content: "\2a";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the username in a div and float all the divs to the left.